# Accessing local MP3 id3 properties with ExternalInterface

Tags: actionscript-3, mp3, sandbox, id3, externalinterface

I need to run a swf inside an Extendscript (java) window in Photoshop. The Extendscript part pops up a Folder Selection dialog and lets user to select a folder. Then it sends the Folder path and the list of the .mp3 files in that folder to the swf file. 
The swf can load and play the song
But it can't get the id3 information

The swf is in "Access Network Files Only" mode

I'm pretty sure it is a security issue and wonder if anyone knows of a workaround. Here is my code...

Thanks in advance.

```
var mp3FileList;
var folder;
var songList;
var songsArray:Array = new Array();
var mp3Array:Array = new Array();


if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("transferSongList", transferSongList);
}


//Extendscript opens a Select Folder dialog
//and sends the folder path and the list of .mp3 files inside the selected folder to this swf

function transferSongList(folder, mp3FileList){
    songList=quickReplace(mp3FileList, "%20", " ");
    songsArray = songList.split(",");
    var mp3File:Sound = new Sound();
    mp3File.load(new URLRequest(folder+"/" + songsArray[0]));
    mp3File.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseSound(mp3File));
}

function parseSound(mp3):Function{
    return function(e:Event):void {
        //IF I REMOVE THE NEXT LINE THE SONG PLAYS   
        alertbox.text=mp3.id3.songName
        mp3.play();

  };
}

function quickReplace(source:String, oldString:String, newString:String):String
{
    return source.split(oldString).join(newString);
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried ?

Comment: @akmozo here's the code. This swf is played inside an Extendscript (java) window. Thanks.

Comment: Try to use an `Event.ID3` event listener to get the `Sound.ID3`, and for your error, try to use a Flash Player debug version which you can download from [here](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) to see if there is an error.